# Not able to get the selected values from Drop down using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy, gsp

I'm trying to add new field to existing gsp page which was written by some other guy.

```
    <g:select name="clientId" multiple = "yes" size = "4" from="${com.mycompany.fleet.partymodel.roles.ClientRole.list()}" class = "filter_combo" optionKey="id" />
```

and by using jQuery he is getting selected values like this

```
var selectedclients = "${clientId}";
console.log(selectedclients); // prints id of selected Clients
```

I'm adding new drop down like this in same page

```
<g:select name="contractId"  multiple = "yes" size = "4" from="${com.mycompany.fleet.rules.Contract.list()}" class = "filter_combo" optionKey="id"/>
```

and I'm trying to get the selected values using jQuery like this

```
var selectedcontracts = "${contractId}";
```

but its not fetching the selected values... am I doing anything wrong here?

What does the `${clientId}` mean exactly?

Comment: the `from` tag may be the issue. Are you including the source of the `from` tag as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that is using JQuery, that is just putting the current value for `clientId` into the javascript for `var selectedclients = "${clientId}";` using standard GSP templating.

ie:  when the page is generated, `${clientId}` gets replaced with the value in the model

Are you adding `contractId` to the model in the Controller?

One thing to watch out for here is that if the `clientId` or `contractId` has a double quote in them (ie, if clientId was `Tim"busy" Yates`, then this will generate invalid javascript, as the generated code would look like:

```
var selectedclients = "Tim "working" Yates" ;
```

However, if it's just an integer id then I guess this would be ok

Comment: yes you are right tim_yates! the value was passing from controller.. Thanks  alot!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var selectedcontracts = $('select [name="contractId"]').val();
```